# How to bulk edit Wordpress Images to add title and alt attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently doing the SEO for a client, unfortunately I quoted him before seeing the size of the job, so now I'm stuck with 2,000+ image entries that have no title/alt tags.

I've tried https://forrst.com/posts/Add_Missing_Alt_tags_to_Images_WordPress_Conte-DMO

And the plugin SEO Friendly Images, and a few other plugins with no success.

My question is there a way to bulk edit the images?

Cheers.

Comment: for something like this, I usually just use a php script that runs a query using $wpdb. But in your case, you can't really "bulk edit" different images with different title/alt tags, unless you want them to be all the same thing, which isn't very good anyways.